# Preparing Qt for Windows

Tags: c++, qt, clion

I'm trying to setup Qt inside windows 8.1 using jetbrains Clion IDE but it does not show anything after compiling a simple test project. This is my `main.cpp` file:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets/qpushbutton.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication *app = new QApplication(argc, argv);
    QPushButton *X = new QPushButton("test");
    X->show();
    return app->exec();
}
```

This is my `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)
project(QtTest)

set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "C:\\Qt\\Qt5.5.0\\5.5\\mingw492_32\\")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(QtTest WIN32 ${SOURCE_FILES})

find_package(Qt5Core REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Gui REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Multimedia REQUIRED)

qt5_use_modules(QtTest Core Widgets Gui Multimedia)
target_link_libraries(QtTest Qt5::Widgets Qt5::Gui Qt5::Core Qt5::Multimedia)
```

The output:

```
Process finished with exit code -1073741515 (0xC0000135)
```

Now I want some help to solve this problem.

Comment: It looks like it's crashed, what does your debugger say?

Comment: @cmannett85 what do you mean by "debugger"?? after running it just show this error

Comment: *Off topic #1*: note that the `app` and `X` variables are not freed in this code, it's a memory leak.

Comment: *Off topic #2*: Just curious, why don't you use Qt Creator?

Comment: @kefir500 oh, thanks but it is just a test application :-) I'm doing this project for my advanced programming course and unfortunatly I'm not allowed to use UI generators, so I decided to go with Clion (mainly because I have worked with intellij in my previous project) also I prepared it well in linux environment, but it is not working in windows :(

Comment: @Kian You mean a drag-n-drop GUI builder (Qt Designer)? You can use Qt Creator without it. Just uncheck the **"Generate form"** option when creating *Qt Widgets* project, then no `ui` files will be generated, allowing you to use just plain C++ and Qt code.

Comment: You shouldn't write anything beyond a Hello World without at least _knowing_ what a debugger is. Educate yourself.

Comment: @cmannett85 yeah, probably you are right. I think this is the debuggers output: `gdb: unknown target exception 0xc0000135 at 0x77a9d4f2`

Comment: Post the entire GDB stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

The explicit memory management is unnecessary. You should also never need to use explicit Qt module prefixes - if you do, the build is not configured correctly. Finally, never use the `qclass.h` includes, use `QClass`.

Your code should read as follows. When your environment is correctly configured, it should build and run without any errors.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPushButton>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  QPushButton button("test");
  button.show();
  return app.exec();
}
```